# How to read StateNotifierProvider.family without passing value?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

I have implemented StateNotifierProvider with ".family" modifier:

```
class OrderReviewNotifier extends StateNotifier<OrderReviewState> {
  final OrderReviewRepository repository;

  OrderReviewNotifier(
    this.repository,
    int orderId,
  ) : super(OrderReviewState.initial(orderId));

  Future<void> getOrderItems() async {
    //.....
  }
}

final orderReviewProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose
    .family<OrderReviewNotifier, OrderReviewState, int>(
  (ref, orderId) {
    return OrderReviewNotifier(
      ref.watch(orderReviewRepositoryProvider),
      orderId,
    );
  },
);
```

Then in Consumer I watch it:

```
        Consumer(
            builder: (context, watch, child) {
              
              final state = watch(orderReviewProvider(order.id));

             //.....
            },
          );
```

But when I want to read it, I need to pass `order.id` too:

```
                  onTap: () {
                    context
                        .read(orderReviewProvider(order.id).notifier)
                        .getOrderItems();
                  },
```

When I want to send events to notifier from another file, I don't have `order.id`.
How to get out of this situation?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just pass the id as a parameter to the other component? It's hard to tell from the example provided.

Comment: @AlexHartford, there is no reason, I can do this, but it looks not clean. Or maybe I'm just dramatizing.

Comment: There's definitely nothing wrong with passing an id around components!

Comment: @AlexHartford, but this id is useless in other widgets and needed only in StateNotifier.

Comment: I'm getting the same use case here: i can pass the same id for other widgets, but it looks no clean.

Comment: @SalahAdDin, hello, please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out.
All I needed was `StateProvider`.

```
final selectedOrderProvider = StateProvider<Order?>((ref) => null);
```

Then in orderReviewProvider I can easily get orderId.

```
final orderReviewProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<OrderReviewNotifier, OrderReviewState>(
  (ref) {
    return OrderReviewNotifier(
      ref.read,
      orderId: ref.watch(selectedOrderProvider).state!.id,
      repository: ref.watch(orderReviewRepositoryProvider),
    );
  },
);


class OrderReviewNotifier extends StateNotifier<OrderReviewState> {
  OrderReviewNotifier(
    this.read, {
    required int orderId,
    required this.repository,
  }) : super(OrderReviewState.initial(orderId)) {
    getOrderItems();
  }

  final Reader read;

  final OrderReviewRepository repository;

  Future<void> getOrderItems() async {
    state = state.copyWith(
      isLoading: true,
      error: null,
    );
    final result = await repository.getOrderItems(state.orderId);
    final checkedItemIds = await repository.getCheckedItemIds(state.orderId);

    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }

    result.when(
      data: (data) {
        final isAllItemsChecked = !checkedItemIds.containsValue(false) &&
            checkedItemIds.length >= data.length;

        state = state.copyWith(
          orderItems: data,
          checkedItemIds: checkedItemIds,
          isAllItemsChecked: isAllItemsChecked,
        );
      },
      error: (message) {
        state = state.copyWith(
          error: message,
        );
      },
    );

    state = state.copyWith(
      isLoading: false,
    );
  }
}
```

The documentation describes the work with this well: [link](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/StateProvider-class.html).

Comment: Actually, I'm doing the same, but still i have to pass the state provider with id to all widget children, and it looks unclean.

Comment: @SalahAdDin, you don't need to pass `StateProvider` to all widgets, but only to children, that require `StateProvider`, using `Consumer` or `HookWidget`.

Comment: That's why I'm doing actually, but it still looks ugly, hahahahha